# Atomic increment operation in C++?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

Is ++i an atomic (thread-safe) operation in C++. If so, which standard and compiler?

Does this even exist somewhere? I couldn't find information about this on the Internet. atomic<> guarantees this. But if you do it without it. Usually ++i is not an atomic operation? Are they on all platforms, etc.

Comment: It's not guaranteed to be atomic by the C++ standard.

Comment: [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/is-incrementing-an-int-effectively-atomic-in-specific-cases) and [Are +=, |=, &= etc atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468857/are-etc-atomic)